# DeclarationError: Undeclared indentifier. Did you mean "Tinder_Token_ID"?

Tags: erc-721, ethers.js

I am new in this field, and i am running into problems in my very first attempt. below is my code in my .sol file

```
/ SPDX-License-identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract TinderERC721 is ERC721URIStorage {
    

    uint256 TINDER_TOKEN_1D;
   
    constructor() ERC721("LoveNFT", "LN") {}

    function mintNFT(address _userOne, address _userTwo, string memory tokenURI) public{
        _mint(_userOne, TINDER_TOKEN_ID);
        _setTokenURI(TINDER_TOKEN_ID, tokenURI);
         TINDER_TOKEN_ID++;

         _mint(_userTwo, TINDER_TOKEN_ID);
         _setTokenURI(TINDER_TOKEN_ID, TokenURI);
         TINDER_TOKEN_ID++;

    }
}
```

the image below shows the error message.

[image]

Could anyone kindly explain to me in simple terms what i should do now, i have been stuck here for the pas 8 hours.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity is case sensitive. When you write a parameters, make sure the name matches.

Instead of `TINDER_TOKEN_1D`you wrote `TINDER_TOKEN_ID`
Instead of `tokenURI` you wrote `TokenURI`